# Xcode 4.3's 'estimated app store size' is considerably different than .ipa file, why?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, app-store

I had been using Xcode 4.2 up till last week and I was using the size of my .ipa file to estimate the size of my app in the app store (I've kept it just under 20MB) and its been pretty consistent.  I upgraded to Xcode 4.3 2 days ago and it has a new feature to indicate to you the 'Estimated App Store Size' after you 'Archive' your app, the estimated size its giving me is fully 2x the size of my .ipa file I've been using to guess my app store size and its WAY over 20MB according to Xcode 4.3!

So, which one is right? :O

EDIT: Just released the app today and it looks like the ipa was the closest guess in my case the app shows in the store as 17.6MB and the .ipa is (now) 16.7MB, 3.3MB binary.

Comment: +1 Wow... I never even saw that line. Mine also reports 2x my .ipa file size... at 18.6 MB I'm supposedly dangerously close to going over the limit : |

Comment: I also just discovered that .ipa filesize isn't what you should be watching, you should be watching the size of your app binary + the zipped size of your bundle (w/out the binary). http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/40575-Game-size-CHECK-under-10mb

Comment: isn't that was a .ipa file **is**? The .ipa contains both the binary and the resources - if anything it would be smaller with the zipping of the resources. Even adding the binary size + the resources zipped, I still don't get anywhere near the supposed "Estimated App Store Size".

Comment: @Steve Thats what I thought but after performing the calculation according to the above method (which is also what an Apple Dev suggests doing in the dev forums) I got 23.7MB via 'the method' while my .ipa file was 19.9MB

Comment: Well that difference (< 4 MB) could be accounted for by simply doing the PNG optimizations Xcode does for you when it builds the project and tweaking the zip settings - it's definitely not 2x the size! - So I'm still confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can more or less ignore XCode's "estimate" (or roughly cut it in half) for most iOS apps.  The IPA is the size of the app.  This doubling in estimated size seems to be linked to the architecture build overhaul in 4.3.2.  Since you are likely building your app for "armv6 armv7", it's doubling it for some reason.  I recently uploaded my previously 15MB app with minor changes.  XCode shows 30MB estimated size for the archive.  Sure enough, the new app is actually 15.2MB on the app store.

If you want a *better* estimate, simply right-click the archive in the Organizer and select Show in Finder.  There, you can again right-click and drill down into the archive to see the actual package and contents.  The app is the only thing of substantive size and is a very good estimation of the App Store size.

Comment: I believe the estimate takes the size of the .app plus the size of the dSYM file, compressed together. Perhaps Apple had planned/does plan to bundle dSYMs inside ipas, and so estimates based on their inclusion, but in fact doesn't include them?

Comment: Please note that if you're looking at iOS9 and above, App Slicing negates most of this discussion.

Answer (score 4):

The App store encrypts most of your binary executable, which renders it no-longer compressible inside the new ipa file that the App store creates for each customer.  You have to look at the uncompressed size of your binary executable and add most of that size to your zip-ed .ipa size to get the new App store .ipa size.

Comment: I mentioned a link that has the same suggestion: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/40575-Game-size-CHECK-under-10mb And going by that method I get 23.7MB total instead of 19.9 (size of my .ipa).  But that doesn't explain why Xcode 4.3 says my estimated size is 39.8MB

Comment: I believe this is the actual answer to the question "Why is the app store size surprisingly bigger than the "ipa" size?"

Comment: According to Apple's technical Q&A article on app size, they explain that the whole binary is compressed, but the encryption of the app binary reduces the effectiveness: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1795/_index.html