# Unity - Updating App on iTunes increased the file size

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, itunes

I am using unity 5.3.4. I uploaded a 48 MB iPA to the App store and it got approved and went live. The size displayed in iTunes when the app went live was around 70 MB. I made a few changes in the game and uploaded a new version of the game. The iPA size this time was 47 MB. Now when the game went live on the AppStore, on an iPhone 5, it shows the game size to be 189MB, on an iPad and in iTunes on my mac, it shows the file size to be 215MB! But when I download it on my mac, it shows the filze size that it is downloading to be 77mb. Why am I able to see these different build sizes in these different places? What is the actual build size that will be downloaded when I download it on a phone or iPad?

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620322/estimated-apps-store-size or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353859/xcode-4-3s-estimated-app-store-size-is-considerably-different-than-ipa-file

Comment: thanks for the reply. This is more for estimating the size. I am confused so as to why I am seeing different sizes everywhere - different on iPhone , iPad and iTunes on mac. And then when I download it on the mac, it is a different size altogether.

Comment: I think it comes from the different architecture which results in different app sizes according to device.

Comment: but then how is it 70 mb when downloading in iTunes on the mac? which architecture is it downloading for there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, while downloading in TestFlight or iTunes, it shows the space that the app is going to take after installing on the device and not the actual file size being downloaded.